# Error when using array_filter with static functions in class

Tags: php, class, function, static, array-filter

i have a class

like this

```
class im_a_class
{

 static function not_empty() {...}

 function render() { return array_filter($array,'self::not_empty') };
}
```

this code works in php 5.3.0 but doesn't work in version 5.2.8.

i had to put it out and use it like this

```
function not_empty() {...}

class im_a_class
{

 function render() { return array_filter($array,'not_empty'); }

}
```

this way it works but...

i want to know what options do i have.

please help thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
return array_filter($array, array(__CLASS__, 'not_empty'));
```

Comment: It can bring this PHP Strict Standards: array_filter() expects parameter 2 to be a valid callback, non-static method

Answer (score 1):

I'm surprised 5.3.0 allows this.  `self::` means nothing to `array_filter`, as `array_filter` is not part of your class.

You should be accessing the function using `im_a_class::not_empty` (which is the function's fully-qualified name)

Comment: this worked like this:
`array_filter($array, \__CLASS__  .'::not_empty')`
thanks.